# Convert Angular 2 signature-pad JSON to jQuery.signaturePad jSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, angular

I'm using Rails + Angular. In my Rails code, I use jQuery.signaturePad, that generates output like:

```
[
  {"lx"=>0.0, "ly"=>8.0, "mx"=>0.0, "my"=>7.0},
  {"lx"=>1.0, "ly"=>10.0, "mx"=>0.0, "my"=>8.0},
  ...
]
```

But, since I have a project boundation that I can't use jQuery for Angular code, I decided to use [Angular2 SignaturePad](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-signaturepad).

So, when I try the following:

```
@ViewChild(SignaturePad) signaturePad: SignaturePad;
.
.
.
drawComplete() {
  this.signaturePad.toData()
}
```

It outputs as:

```
[
  [
    {x: 85.5, y: 66, time: 1568119306312, color: "#145394"},
    {x: 90.5, y: 66, time: 1568119306375, color: "#145394"},
    {x: 97.5, y: 75, time: 1568119306407, color: "#145394"},
    {x: 105.5, y: 89, time: 1568119306424, color: "#145394"}
  ],
  [
    {x: 120.5, y: 112, time: 1568119306440, color: "#145394"},
    {x: 134.5, y: 130, time: 1568119306456, color: "#145394"},
    {x: 146.5, y: 151, time: 1568119306473, color: "#145394"},
    {x: 159.5, y: 171, time: 1568119306489, color: "#145394"}
  ]
]
```

Where each array inside array represents each stroke in the Canvas.

**Is there a way I can convert the above Angular signatirePad JSON format to  the jQuery signaturePad JSON format?**

So that I can user the same signature data to render sign in Rails as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the conversion. So, in the following example (output of **Angular2 signature-pad**):

```
[
  [
    1 -> {x: 85.5, y: 66, time: 1568119306312, color: "#145394"},
    2 -> {x: 90.5, y: 66, time: 1568119306375, color: "#145394"},
    3 -> {x: 97.5, y: 75, time: 1568119306407, color: "#145394"},
    4 -> {x: 105.5, y: 89, time: 1568119306424, color: "#145394"}
  ],
  [
    5 -> {x: 120.5, y: 112, time: 1568119306440, color: "#145394"},
    6 -> {x: 134.5, y: 130, time: 1568119306456, color: "#145394"},
    7 -> {x: 146.5, y: 151, time: 1568119306473, color: "#145394"},
    8 -> {x: 159.5, y: 171, time: 1568119306489, color: "#145394"}
  ]
]
```

Numbered 1,2,3,4...for understanding...

The **jQuery signature-pad** output take it like:

```
l = 2, m = 1
l = 3, m = 2
.
.
.
l = 8, m = 7
```

So, the output similar to **jQuery.signature-pad** would be:

```
[
  {lx: 90.5, ly: 66, mx: 85.5, my: 66},
  {lx: 97.5, ly: 75, mx: 90.5, my: 66},
  {lx: 105.5, ly: 89, mx: 97.5, my: 75},

  {lx: 134.5, ly: 130, mx: 120.5, my: 112},
  {lx: 146.5, ly: 151, mx: 134.5, my: 130},
  {lx: 159.5, ly: 171, mx: 146.5, my: 151},
]
```